# force automake and autoconf to set the -lz flag behind the compilation line, and do it without changing the .ac files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, zlib, autotools

I am having some source package whose developer is comfortably using an ancient GCC version, where compilation requires the -lz flags before the object specs. The package is very "branchy" and the automake and autoconf very "stuffy" so I have two questions:

First question is how to configure my autotools to set the -lz flag behind?

Second, is it possible to force setting at back of this -lz flag without messing with the makefile.ac and configure.ac files? Since this is not my software package always editing these files whenever I am doing a new build is simply not an option.

Note that if I copy the compilation line that throws the error and just put the -lz and -lxerces-c flags at the end then it works. So I have to somehow change this in autotools.

UPDATE:

Well I managed to somehow fix it by running the badly configured line with
`$ g++ line_contents -lz -lxerces-c`
(making sure to be in the right directory)
And then I just had the idea of running make again, it seemed that automake considered that step passed and just went forward.

Still, it would be nice to find an answer on how to change the order with the autotools!

Comment: Set `LDFLAGS` environment variable when configuring?

Comment: sure, ./configure --help lists a series of environment variables that would override the default config, but the LDFLAGS seems to only set custom locations and not the order of the -lz call. So it would only be useful if my libz would not be in a default location.

Comment: Why the order of linker flags matter for you?

Comment: I already regressed from gcc/g++ 5 to 4.7 but the compiler had issue with the lz flags being in fron of the object. This is well known for the past five years or so, the compiler in newer versions expects them at the end and it makes every old source autoconf break during build.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own "gcc" for that task.
Python or bash script that check if one of arguments is `-lz`,
and reoder them and then call real `gcc`.
After that just run `CC=path/to/your/gcc ./configure` and all stuff should work.

Comment: Thanks, that's very smart but I am not going to set this to accepted because  I need an answer that uses the autotools somehow. Setting up my own gcc script just for this project can be cumbersome too. Although as a simple and smart idea you have my thumb up!